# JSON parsing does not go through array

Tags: json, influxdb, telegraf

I am currently receiving data from a kafka topic to the telegraf kafka_consumer plugin.

The structure of my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  metadata: {
    generated: Long Integer,
    url: String,
    title: String,
    api: String,
    count: Integer,
    status: Integer
  },
  bbox: [
    minimum longitude,
    minimum latitude,
    minimum depth,
    maximum longitude,
    maximum latitude,
    maximum depth
  ],
  features: [
    {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {
        mag: Decimal,
        place: String,
        time: Long Integer,
        updated: Long Integer,
        tz: Integer,
        url: String,
        detail: String,
        felt:Integer,
        cdi: Decimal,
        mmi: Decimal,
        alert: String,
        status: String,
        tsunami: Integer,
        sig:Integer,
        net: String,
        code: String,
        ids: String,
        sources: String,
        types: String,
        nst: Integer,
        dmin: Decimal,
        rms: Decimal,
        gap: Decimal,
        magType: String,
        type: String
      },
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          longitude,
          latitude,
          depth
        ]
      },
      id: String
    },
    …
  ]
}
```

I manage to retrieve some of the information I'm interested in, but unfortunately no matter how big the Features array is, the parsing only retrieves one element
[image]

Here is my telegraf.conf file:

```
# Configuration for telegraf agent
[agent]
  ## Default data collection interval for all inputs
  interval = "10s"
  ## Rounds collection interval to 'interval'
  ## ie, if interval="10s" then always collect on :00, :10, :20, etc.
  round_interval = true

  ## Telegraf will send metrics to outputs in batches of at most
  ## metric_batch_size metrics.
  ## This controls the size of writes that Telegraf sends to output plugins.
  metric_batch_size = 1000

  ## Maximum number of unwritten metrics per output.  Increasing this value
  ## allows for longer periods of output downtime without dropping metrics at the
  ## cost of higher maximum memory usage.
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000

  ## Collection jitter is used to jitter the collection by a random amount.
  ## Each plugin will sleep for a random time within jitter before collecting.
  ## This can be used to avoid many plugins querying things like sysfs at the
  ## same time, which can have a measurable effect on the system.
  collection_jitter = "0s"

  ## Default flushing interval for all outputs. Maximum flush_interval will be
  ## flush_interval + flush_jitter
  flush_interval = "10s"
  ## Jitter the flush interval by a random amount. This is primarily to avoid
  ## large write spikes for users running a large number of telegraf instances.
  ## ie, a jitter of 5s and interval 10s means flushes will happen every 10-15s
  flush_jitter = "0s"

  ## Collected metrics are rounded to the precision specified. Precision is
  ## specified as an interval with an integer + unit (e.g. 0s, 10ms, 2us, 4s).
  ## Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s".
  ##
  ## By default or when set to "0s", precision will be set to the same
  ## timestamp order as the collection interval, with the maximum being 1s:
  ##   ie, when interval = "10s", precision will be "1s"
  ##       when interval = "250ms", precision will be "1ms"
  ##
  ## Precision will NOT be used for service inputs. It is up to each individual
  ## service input to set the timestamp at the appropriate precision.
  precision = "0s"

  ## Override default hostname, if empty use os.Hostname()
  hostname = ""
  ## If set to true, do no set the "host" tag in the telegraf agent.
  omit_hostname = false

###############################################################################
#                            OUTPUT PLUGINS                                   #
###############################################################################


# # Configuration for sending metrics to InfluxDB 2.0
 [[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
   ## The URLs of the InfluxDB cluster nodes.
   ##
   ## Multiple URLs can be specified for a single cluster, only ONE of the
   ## urls will be written to each interval.
   ##   ex: urls = ["https://us-west-2-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com"]
   urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]

   ## Token for authentication.
   token = $INFLUX_TOKEN

   ## Organization is the name of the organization you wish to write to.
   organization = "earthWatch"

   ## Destination bucket to write into.
   bucket = "telegraf"

[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
  ## Kafka brokers.
  brokers = ["localhost:9092"]

  ## Topics to consume.
  topics = ["general-events"]

  ## Maximum length of a message to consume, in bytes (default 0/unlimited);
  ## larger messages are dropped
  max_message_len = 0

  data_format="json"
  
  json_query = "features.#.properties"
  json_string_fields = ["place", "url", "detail", "alert", "status", "net", "code", "ids", "sources", "types", "magType", "type", "mag", "time", "updated", "tz", "felt", "cdi", "mmi", "tsunami", "sig", "nst", "dmin", "rms", "gap"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea was to implement a tag for each object/value desired and to change my telegraf.conf, thanks to user jpower

more info [here](https://community.influxdata.com/t/cant-parse-properly-json-coming-from-kafka/26492)